# Regex to remove lines in file(s) that ending with same or defined letters

Tags: regex, string, macos, bash, sed

i need a bash script for **mac osx** working in this way:

```
./script.sh * folder/to/files/ 
#
# or #
#
./script.sh xx folder/to/files/
```

This script

- read a list of files
- open each file and read each lines
- if lines ended with the same letters ('*****' mode) or with custom letters ('**xx**') then
  remove line and **RE-SAVE** file
- backup original file

---

My first approach to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ck init params
if [ $# -le 0 ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 <letters>"
  exit 0
fi

# list files in current dir
list=`ls BRUTE*` 
for i in $list 
do 

  # prepare regex    
  case $1 in
       "*") REGEXP="^.*(.)\1+$";;
       *) REGEXP="^.*[$1]$";;
  esac    
  FILE=$i

  # backup file
  cp $FILE $FILE.bak

  # removing line with same letters
  sed -Ee "s/$REGEXP//g" -i '' $FILE
  cat $FILE | grep -v "^$"

done

exit 0
```

But it doesn't work as i want....

What's wrong?
How can i fix this script?

---

## Example:

```
$cat BRUTE02.dat BRUTE03.dat
aa
ab
ac
ad
ee
ef
ff
hhh
$
```

If i use '*****' i want all files that ended with **same letters** to be clean.
If i use '**ff**' i want all files that ended with '**ff**' to be clean.

---

Ah, it's on **Mac OSx**. Remember that sed is a little different from classical linux sed.

## man sed

> ```
>  sed [-Ealn] command [file ...]
>  sed [-Ealn] [-e command] [-f command_file] [-i extension] [file
> ```
>
> ...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The sed utility reads the specified files, or the standard input
>   if no files are specified, modifying the input as specified by a list
>   of commands.  The
>        input is then written to the standard output.
>
> ```
>  A single command may be specified as the first argument to sed.
> ```
>
> Multiple commands may be specified by using the -e or -f options.  All
>   commands are applied
>        to the input in the order they are specified regardless of their
>   origin.
>
> ```
>  The following options are available:
>
>  -E      Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern)
> ```
>
> regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's). 
>   The re_format(7) manual page
>                fully describes both formats.
>
> ```
>  -a      The files listed as parameters for the ``w'' functions
> ```
>
> are created (or truncated) before any processing begins, by default. 
>   The -a option causes
>                sed to delay opening each file until a command containing
>   the related ``w'' function is applied to a line of input.
>
> ```
>  -e command
>          Append the editing commands specified by the command
> ```
>
> argument to the list of commands.
>
> ```
>  -f command_file
>          Append the editing commands found in the file
> ```
>
> command_file to the list of commands.  The editing commands should
>   each be listed on a separate line.
>
> ```
>  -i extension
>          Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified
> ```
>
> extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be
>   saved.  It is not recom-
>                mended to give a zero-length extension when in-place
>   editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations
>   where disk space is
>                exhausted, etc.
>
> ```
>  -l      Make output line buffered.
>
>  -n      By default, each line of input is echoed to the standard
> ```
>
> output after all of the commands have been applied to it.  The -n
>   option suppresses this
>                behavior.
>
> ```
>  The form of a sed command is as follows:
>
>        [address[,address]]function[arguments]
>
>  Whitespace may be inserted before the first address and the
> ```
>
> function portions of the command.
>
> ```
>  Normally, sed cyclically copies a line of input, not including
> ```
>
> its terminating newline character, into a pattern space, (unless there
>   is something left
>        after a ``D'' function), applies all of the commands with
>   addresses that select that pattern space, copies the pattern space to
>   the standard output, append-
>        ing a newline, and deletes the pattern space.
>
> ```
>  Some of the functions use a hold space to save all or part of the
> ```
>
> pattern space for subsequent retrieval.

anything else?
it's clear my problem?

thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of the pair of single-quotes in your sed cmd? `sed -Ee "s/$REGEXP//g" -i '' $FILE` . What you're trying to do, and how you're doing it is straight sed usage that I would expect to work anywhere. The OsX manual quote doesn't help, OR you explictly quote from the man page what you think makes this different. AND finally, you write, "doesn't work as I want". please show 1 what you want, 2 what you are getting. Good luck.

Comment: Sed on MAC OSX not use direct output. Using `-i '' ` bypass check.

Comment: 'not use direct ouput'. please note this quote from the man page your provided : `The input is then written to the standard output.` This is just like any other sed ;-), honest! Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem!

```
grep '\(.\)\1[^\r\n]$' *
```

on MAC OSX, `( ) { }`, etc... must be quoted!!!

Solved, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know bash shell too well so I can't evaluate what the failure is.
This is just an observation of the regex as understood (this may be wrong).

The `*` mode regex looks ok:
`^.*(.)\1+$   that ended with same letters..`

But the literal mode might not do what you think.
current: `^.*[$1]$  that ended with 'literal string'`
This shouldn't use a character class.

Change it to: `^.*$1$`

Realize though the string in $1 (before it goes into the regex) should be escaped
incase there are any regex metacharacters contained within it.

Otherwise, do you intend to have a character class?

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN {$arg = shift; $re = $arg eq "*" ? qr/([[:alpha:]])\1$/ : qr/$arg$/}
    /$re/ && next || print
'
```

Example:

```
echo "aa
ab
ac
ad
ee
ef
ff" | perl -ne '
    BEGIN {$arg = shift; $re = $arg eq "*" ? qr/([[:alpha:]])\1$/ : qr/$arg$/}
    /$re/ && next || print
' '*'
```

produces

```
ab
ac
ad
ee
ef
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible issue:

- When you put `*` on the command line, the shell replaces it with the name of all the files in your directory. Your `$1` will never equal `*`.

And some tips:

- You can replace replace:

This:

```
# list files in current dir
list=`ls BRUTE*` 
for i in $list
```

With:

```
for i in BRUTE*
```

- And:

This:

cat $FILE | grep -v "^$"

With:

```
grep -v "^$" $FILE
```

Besides the possible issue, I can't see anything jumping out at me. What do you mean *clean*? Can you give an example of what a file should look like before and after and what the command would look like?

Comment: you don't need `ls` to list files using a for loop. `for file in BRUTE*` suffice

Comment: @bash-o-logist: You don't need the `ls` command first. Remember that each command is first interpreted by the shell. The shell searches for its meta-characters and replaces them with the names of the matching files. This will work with any command. Try `echo *` (no quotes) vs. `echo "*"` (with quotes) and feel the power of the shell. Use the shell, Luke.

Comment: I am reminding you that you don't need to `ls` to use with a for loop if you only wants to list the file names. Why are you reminding me instead ? :). To overcome the problem of shell globbing, in bash , we can turn on nullglob.

Comment: @bash-o-logist: Sorry. I thought this was a reply to my post where I mentioned that you can use `for i in BRUTE*` instead of the original poster who did the `list=$(ls BRUTE*)`.